# Toggle the state value with a click in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm displaying a certain div when a user clicks a button(really an image)

```
<img src={notification} className="search_bar_icons" onClick={this.props.open_notifications}/>
```

When the user clicks this image i'm changing the state of the div i want to show to 'true'

```
open_notification() {
    this.setState({
        showNotification: true,
    });
}
```

This is working correctly. But i want to set state as 'false', if the user clicks the image again. How can i do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can toggle your value with

```
this.setState({ showNotification: !this.state.showNotification });
```

**Update.** For now, a better approach of using previous state inside of the setState is:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({ showNotification: !prevState.showNotification }));
```

Comment: I think a side note would be to set the default state to false. I know that the expression @andrew provided would still work, but I think having the default state set correctly would make it more easily readable/maintainable. Just my 0.02$